# Inserting input field inline with header tag

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to have h3 text and input field in one line (h3 aligned to left, input aligned to right, with the same vertical position).

I have tried `form-inline` class, but it doesn't work the way I want.

Code:

```
   <div class="col-md-6">
      <form class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group">
          <h3 class="pull-left">Upcoming Events</h3>
          <input type="text" class="form-control pull-right" placeholder="Country/Region">
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
```

Here is how it looks like (I added second column with hardcoded margins to show how I want it to look like): http://www.bootply.com/f7QEh7oeqF

Any idea how can I format it the way I want?

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of `display: inline-block;` on the `form-group` class.

Then you can modify the `margin-top` attribute of the header class as you wish, to vertically align the header with the input field.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a margin and set .form-group width at 100%.
http://www.bootply.com/uvjb30F2ji

Answer (score 0):

Do this for your forms instead:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-6 h3">Upcoming Events</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Country/Region" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

and add this CSS:

```
.h3 {
    margin-top: 0;
    line-height: 34px;
}
```

and if the forms are too far above the lists, you can add the following CSS:

```
.form-group {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

NOTE: I changed your `h3` tags to `label` tags with the `.h3` class because form controls need a label associated with it for screen readers to work properly. Not a huge deal normally but helps with accessibility.

See **[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/084FgtHQxTKWbhE3zzBv?p=preview)**